# DATEDIFF based on next populated column in row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query in SQL Server that is giving me a result set that looks something like this:

| ID | DaysInState | DaysInState2 | DaysInState3 | DaysInState4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-07 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | 2022-04-09 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 2022-04-11 | 2022-04-15 | NULL | 2022-04-18 |
| 4 | 2022-04-11 | NULL | NULL | 2022-04-18 |

I need to calculate the number of days that a given item spent in a given state. The challenge I am facing is 'looking ahead' in the row. Using row 1 as an example these would be the following values:

- DaysInState: 6 (`DATEDIFF(day, '2022-04-11', '2022-04-07')`)
- DaysInState2: 12 (`DATEDIFF(day, '2022-04-07', GETDATE())`)
- DaysInState3: NULL
- DaysInState4: NULL

The challenging part here is that for each column in each row, I have to look at all the columns to the right of the reference column to see if a date exists to use in `DATEDIFF`. If a date is not found to the right of the reference column then `GETDATE()` is used. The table below shows what the result set should look like:

| ID | DaysInState | DaysInState2 | DaysInState3 | DaysInState4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 12 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | 10 | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | 4 | 3 | NULL | 1 |
| 4 | 7 | NULL | NULL | 1 |

I can write fairly convoluted `CASE...WHEN` statements for each column such that

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN DaysInState IS NOT NULL AND DaysInState2 IS NOT NULL THEN DateDiff(day, DaysInState, DaysInState2)
        WHEN DaysInState IS NOT NULL AND DaysInState2 IS NULL AND DaysInState3 IS NOT NULL THEN DateDiff(day, DaysInState, DaysInState3)
    ...
    END
...
```

However this isn't very maintainable when states are added / removed.  Is there a more dynamic approach to solving this problem that doesn't involve lengthy `CASE` statements or just generally a "better" approach that maybe I am not seeing?

Comment: You can use `COALESCE()` so you don't end up in case expression hell. `DATEDIFF(COALESCE(DaysInState1, GETDATE()), COALESCE(DaysInState2, DaysInstate3, DaysInState4, GETDATE()) as DaysInState` would likely work. This is a little different logic than yours in that if DaysInState1 is NULL then you will get a `0` back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COALESCE function allows multiple parameters, evaluating them from left to right, returning the first non-null value, eliminating the need for nesting:

```
Daysinstate1=
   datediff(day,
            Daysinstate1,
            Coalesce(daysinstate2
                    ,Daysinstate3
                    ,Daysinstate4
                    ,Getdate())
            )
```

Comment: As many have mentioned, this is the most straightforward approach I think.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible to adjust the query generating your result set, I'd like to suggest a new approach.  One advantage is that it can handle additional DayInState variables (5,6,7,...).

Rewrite your query so that your results have three columns: one for ID, one for "DayInState" number, and one for the date.  That is, no NULL values returned.  Union the result set with the distinct IDs, an exceedingly large "DayInState" number, and the result of GETDATE().  Then you can use DATEDIFF() with LAG() to look at the next dates.

Here's a working example in SQL Server using your data:

```
begin
declare @temp table (id int,state_num int,dt date)
insert into @temp values
(1,1,'2022-04-01'),
(1,2,'2022-04-07'),
(2,2,'2022-04-09'),
(3,1,'2022-04-11'),
(3,2,'2022-04-15'),
(3,3,'2022-04-18'),
(4,1,'2022-04-11'),
(4,4,'2022-04-18')
select t.id,t.state_num,DATEDIFF(day,t.dt,LAG(t.dt,1,GETDATE()) over(partition by t.id order by t.state_num desc)) 
from 
(select * from @temp
union (select distinct id,999 as state_num, GETDATE() as dt from @temp) ) t
where t.state_num!=999
order by t.id,t.state_num
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DateTest]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [dbo].[DateTest]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DateTest](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DaysInState] [date] NULL,
    [DaysInState2] [date] NULL,
    [DaysInState3] [date] NULL,
    [DaysInState4] [date] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DateTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[DateTest] ([DaysInState],[DaysInState2],[DaysInState3],[DaysInState4]) VALUES
('2022-04-01','2022-04-07',NULL,NULL),
(NULL,'2022-04-09',NULL,NULL),
('2022-04-11','2022-04-15',NULL,'2022-04-18'),
('2022-04-11',NULL,NULL,'2022-04-18');
GO
```

```
SELECT [ID],[DaysInState],[DaysInState2],[DaysInState3],[DaysInState4] FROM dbo.DateTest
```

Use nested ISNULL to check the next column or pass GETDATE().
Using the variable means you can alter the date if needed.

```
DECLARE @theDate date = GETDATE()
SELECT 
      [DaysInState]  =DATEDIFF(day,[DaysInState], ISNULL([DaysInState2],ISNULL([DaysInState3],ISNULL([DaysInState4],@theDate))))
     ,[DaysInState2] =DATEDIFF(day,[DaysInState2],ISNULL([DaysInState3],ISNULL([DaysInState4],@theDate)))
     ,[DaysInState3] =DATEDIFF(day,[DaysInState3],ISNULL([DaysInState4],@theDate))
     ,[DaysInState4] =DATEDIFF(day,[DaysInState4],@theDate)
FROM dbo.DateTest
```

Your original query

```
SELECT
    [DaysInState]=CASE
        WHEN DaysInState IS NOT NULL AND DaysInState2 IS NOT NULL THEN DateDiff(day, DaysInState, DaysInState2)
        WHEN DaysInState IS NOT NULL AND DaysInState2 IS NULL AND DaysInState3 IS NOT NULL THEN DateDiff(day, DaysInState, DaysInState3)
    END
FROM dbo.DateTest
```

[image: results]